# Merging multiple rows into 1

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I am currently working with a CSV file which contains multiple rows with the same incident number, followed by another column with an equivalent amount of rows with input for the same incident number. My goal is to make only 1 row with the case number and 1 row containing all of the incident rows.

For clarification, there is one column with 26 rows for the same incident number and another column with 26 rows as well. I want to bring it down to 1 row for everything. How can I merge all the info into one row?

Comment: This is unfortunately impossible to answer without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

A toy example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df_2 = df.groupby('incident_number_column').agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x)).reset_index()
```

**ASSUMING** you only have the two columns, this will group all of the text by the incident number and then join together all of the rows with a single separating space. The results should be in `df_2`